Angular: Animation doesnt start
I want to implement a text animation so following:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-animation-demo-with-animejs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
i copied to my file the code:
export class HeroSectionMainTextComponent {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Wrap every letter in a span
    const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-1');
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
      /\S/g,
      "<span class='letter'>$&</span>",
    );

    anime
      .timeline({ loop: true })
      .add({
        targets: '.an-1 .letter',
        scale: [4, 1],
        opacity: [0, 1],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        duration: 950,
        delay: (el, i) => 70 * i,
      })
      .add({
        targets: '.an-1',
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        delay: 1000,
      });
  }
}

but i got an error:
TS18047: 'textWrapper' is possibly 'null'.

so i tried adding ?. like this:
 const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-1');
    textWrapper?.innerHTML = textWrapper?.textContent.replace(
      /\S/g,
      "<span class='letter'>$&</span>",
    );

but it didnt work. How to make it work and why on stackblitz it works?
EDIT:
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var anime: any; // declare like this
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-section-main-text',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './hero-section-main-text.component.html',
  styleUrl: './hero-section-main-text.component.css',
})
export class HeroSectionMainTextComponent {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Wrap every letter in a span
    const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-1');
    if (textWrapper) {
      textWrapper.innerHTML =
        textWrapper?.textContent?.replace(
          /\S/g,
          "<span class='letter'>$&</span>",
        ) || '';
    }

    anime
      .timeline({ loop: true })
      .add({
        targets: '.an-1 .letter',
        scale: [4, 1],
        opacity: [0, 1],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        duration: 950,
        delay: (el: any, i: any) => 70 * i,
      })
      .add({
        targets: '.an-1',
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        delay: 1000,
      });
  }
}

now i dont get any error but the animation simply doesnt start..

We just need to check the left hand side textWrapper property is not null, we can use a if condition to check this! also added  || '' so that the right hand side does not return undefined but empty string instead!
You have strictNullChecks enabled in typescript, could also be due to strict enabled in tsconfig.json
const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-1');
if (textWrapper) {
  textWrapper.innerHTML =
    textWrapper?.textContent?.replace(
      /\S/g,
      "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
    ) || '';
}

full code
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
declare var anime: any; // declare like this
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  imports: [AppModule],
  standalone: true,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Wrap every letter in a span
    const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-1');
    if (textWrapper) {
      textWrapper.innerHTML =
        textWrapper?.textContent?.replace(
          /\S/g,
          "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
        ) || '';
    }

    anime
      .timeline({ loop: true })
      .add({
        targets: '.an-1 .letter',
        scale: [4, 1],
        opacity: [0, 1],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        duration: 950,
        delay: (el, i) => 70 * i,
      })
      .add({
        targets: '.an-1',
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        delay: 1000,
      });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent);

Stackblitz Demo

thanks sir! now i dont have any errors but the animation still doesnt work.. just like plain text, in edit i provide the component.ts file
